# How to create a "pay per node" "pay to publish" type flow in Commerce 2?

Tags: 8, commerce

I'm experimenting with Commerce 2 and Drupal 8.

I want to set up a flow where people can pay for a node-- use cases like classified ad listing (pay per post), event signup (pay to register), and so on.

Here's what I did so far.

- Create a content type **classified ad**.
- Create a product **1 month of ad exposure**.
- Add an *entity reference* field on **classified ad** with the default value set to **1 month of ad exposure**.  Set the display widget for this field to *rendered entity*. Hide this field with field permissions. (This allows the user to create a **classified ad** node and then see an *Add to cart* button for the correct product after saving.)

So far, so good.  But, with this configuration, the **order** doesn't have any information about the original node (content type: **classified ad**).   I need to know which node the purchase/order was made for because I want to publish that node.

So, I changed the **default order type**: I added an *entity reference* to content of type **classified ad**. But how do I populate this *entity reference* field with the correct node?  Or is there a better way to link the node for which the product was purchased with the order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an order and an order item yourself and then add those values, I assume you need to do this from the context of your node anyway and not use a standard "buy this product" form.

A snippet from a project:

```
$order_item_values = [
  'type' => 'order_item_type',
  'title' => 'label',
  'unit_price' => new Price(...),
  ...
];
$order_item = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order_item')->create($order_item_values);
$order_item->save();

$order_type = $this->orderTypeResolver->resolve($order_item);

$stores = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_store')->loadMultiple();
$store = reset($stores);

// Create the new order.
/** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface $order */
$order = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order')->create([
  'type' => $order_type,
  'store_id' => $store->id(),
  'uid' => $this->currentUser()->id(),
  'cart' => FALSE,
]);

$order->addItem($order_item);
$order->save();

$this->cartSession->addCartId($order->id(), CartSessionInterface::COMPLETED);

return $this->redirect('commerce_checkout.form', ['commerce_order' => $order->id()]);
```

You don't even need to use products, you can define an order item that just has a price and reference to your node. But you can also use products to define e.g. the length/price.

Comment: Where does code like this snippet go?

Comment: That's entirely up to you, you can build a form or so that is displayed on the node or a local task or so.